# Convert Sql to Linq, joins, having and group clause

Tags: sql, linq

Can anyone help convert the following sql to linq please?

```
select 
    s.GroupId,
    g.GroupName
from [dbo].[Schedule] s
inner join Groups g on s.GroupId = g.GroupId
inner join GroupMembers gm on g.GroupId = gm.GroupId
where s.CourseId = 2
group by s.GroupId, g.GroupName, g.MaxPersons
having count(gm.PersonId) < g.MaxPersons
```

Thanks

UPDATE

Linqer seems a pretty cool tool thanks! I've got this so far, getting a syntax error that it doesn't recognise p.gm.PersonId. Trying to get my head around linq grouping compared with sql grouping.

```
from s in Schedules
join g in Groups on s.GroupId equals g.GroupId
join gm in GroupMembers on g.GroupId equals gm.GroupId
where
  s.CourseId == 2
group new {s, g} by new {
  s.GroupId,
  g.GroupName,
  g.MaxPersons
} into g
where g.Count(p => p.gm.PersonId != null) < Convert.ToInt64(g.Key.MaxPersons)
select new {
  GroupId = (int?)g.Key.GroupId,
  g.Key.GroupName
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? We can help you fix what you're having issues with, but we won't write the whole thing for you.

Comment: Take a look at this tool. Linqer is a SQL to LINQ conversion tool. [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `gm` to your group type

```
new {s, g, gm}
```